Checkout error after upgrade to Magento 2.4.7 Error: "email" is required. Enter and try again
When clicking on the button: Place Order (in Connected mode and not Connected to the BO), I have this error message:


POST .../rest/store_en/V1/guest-carts/eFlVy14vPXeH9hU5R6BpK2QZiRCYx508/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)


Any help please i'm blocked

After migration to 2.4.7 : The email field has disappeared
Any help please .
Order sending is blocked

There seams to be email component missing in your jslayout. It's usually separated from address components. Any modifications to LayoutProcessor or by layout xml?
Hard to tell why not seeing all the code.
Email should be sent to payment-information endpoint as separate field like:
"email":"email@your.com"
